running bash command through python script
i have a problem with running bash command through python script. my task is that i have to find a minimum possible woring combination of "instrumentations" and "within":
instrumentations = [
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.EnvelopeInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.SystemMessageInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.RouterInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.ActorInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.ActorLoggingInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.AskPatternInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.EventStreamInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.ActorRefInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.akka_25.DispatcherInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.akka_26.DispatcherInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.akka_26.ActorMonitorInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.SchedulerInstrumentation",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.ClusterInstrumentation"
]
within = [
    "^akka.dispatch..*",
    "^akka.event..*",
    "^akka.actor..*",
    "^akka.pattern..*",
    "^akka.cluster..*",
    "^akka.routing..*",
    "kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations..*"
]

so to check my combination manually i have to run this two commands:
sbt assembly

DATADOG_AGENT_IP=127.0.0.1 JAVA_HEAP_MS=1024m JAVA_HEAP_MX=2048m JAVA_HEAP_MS=1024m java -Dconfig.resource=/local-staging-db.conf -Xloggc:./log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -javaagent:kanela-agent-1.0.17.jar -Djava.library.path=native -Duser.timezone=GMT -jar target/scala-2.12/sharaku-web-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

and if the server is breaking, i have to try another combination.
as there are a lot of combinations, i decided to write a script.
so now im stuck on running my command two through the skript:
command2 = """
    java -Dconfig.resource=/local-staging-db.conf \
    -Xloggc:./log/gc.log \
    -XX:+PrintGCDetails \
    -javaagent:kanela-agent-1.0.17.jar \
    -Djava.library.path=native \
    -Duser.timezone=GMT \
    -jar target/scala-2.12/sharaku-web-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    """

    env = os.environ.copy()
    env['DATADOG_AGENT_IP'] = "127.0.0.1"
    env['JAVA_HEAP_MS'] = "1024m"
    env['JAVA_HEAP_MX'] = "2048m"

    # Execute the command
    result = subprocess.run(command2, shell=True, cwd=cwd2, env=env, text=True)

so i tried following ways:

with """ i see this result:

 command2 = """
    java -Dconfig.resource=/local-staging-db.conf \
    -Xloggc:./log/gc.log \
    -XX:+PrintGCDetails \
    -javaagent:kanela-agent-1.0.17.jar \
    -Djava.library.path=native \
    -Duser.timezone=GMT \
    -jar target/scala-2.12/sharaku-web-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    """

    env = os.environ.copy()
    env['DATADOG_AGENT_IP'] = "127.0.0.1"
    env['JAVA_HEAP_MS'] = "1024m"
    env['JAVA_HEAP_MX'] = "2048m"

    # Execute the command
    result = subprocess.run(command2, shell=True, cwd=cwd2, env=env, text=True)

    time.sleep(10)

    print("hey")

    if result.returncode == 0:
        print("JAR completed successfully.", result.poll())
        return True
    else:
        print("JAR failed with code:", result)
        return False


so as i do not see "hey" i suppose that process didn’t terminate.

unification of commands from command2 and env

   command2 = """
    DATADOG_AGENT_IP=127.0.0.1 JAVA_HEAP_MS=1024m JAVA_HEAP_MX=2048m JAVA_HEAP_MS=1024m java -Dconfig.resource=/local-staging-db.conf -Xloggc:./log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -javaagent:kanela-agent-1.0.17.jar -Djava.library.path=native -Duser.timezone=GMT -jar target/scala-2.12/sharaku-web-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    """


    # Execute the command
    result = subprocess.run(command2, shell=True, cwd=cwd2, text=True)

this way gives me he same result as the first one.
also i have tried subprocess.Popen() that gave me much more results (it returned "hey") but i see this mistake:
JAR failed with code: <Popen: returncode: None args: '\n    DATADOG_AGENT_IP=127.0.0.1 JAVA_HEAP_M...>


so im run out of ideas what can i do more. will be grateful for any help. thank you!

Please avoid adding image in question all together. Only use text. Replace images with code or error text. This will help community.

I don't see any use of instrumentations or within in the code.

I can't see any reason why you wouldn't see the Hey message. Did you wait for time.sleep(10) to finish?

Do you really need the sleep while debugging this?

Quibble: Not actually a bash command. shell=True uses sh, not bash. (Even if your operating system installs sh as a link to bash -- which isn't the case on many popular operating systems such as Debian, Ubuntu, or Alpine -- bash disables some of its features when started under the sh name).
